# Lookin for IDE fort html with built-in references to tags (or links) like it was in 1st page from Eversoft

Tags: html, ide, html-editor

basicly, the question is in the title. I tryied to search the web and forums and all I get is a headache. Cant find suitable replecment for Eversoft. Maybe some soft/free ware with plugins. I prefer linux programs. I tried Eclipse (no luck) and  Visual Studio Code (wich offers reference when I highlight the tag, but nothing happens when you click on it)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after deeper research I find this one IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Community Edition), it offers references from mozilla website. It works under Windows or Linux and its free. Here is how [how to get reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editing-html-files.html)